# KMM Library - How to implement Kotlin sealed class/interface into Swift switch

Tags: swift, objective-c, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

So I'm trying out KMM Library (not App) that will be imported into .xcframework/.framework for Xcode project and .aar for Android project.

I wanted to implement UIState (Loading, Success, and Error) so I create a sealed class

```
sealed class UIState<out T> {
    object Loading : UIState<Nothing>()
    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : UIState<T>()
    data class Error(val message: String) : UIState<Nothing>()
}
```

Then make an API call using Coroutine

```
suspend fun getDotaHeroesWithSealedClass(): UIState<List<DotaHero>> =
        when (httpClient.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/heroes").status.value) {
            in 200..299 -> {
                UIState.Success(httpClient.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/heroes").body())
            }
            else -> {
                UIState.Error("An error has occured")
            }
        }
```

After that, I run `./gradlew assembleXCFramework` then link the **.xcframework** into my Xcode project. But the function detected as **UIState< NSArray>**.

[getDotaHeroesWithSealedClass function in Swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4boV.png)

How can I make the function return UIState so I can make a switch case like this

```
switch uiState {
   case .loading:
   case .success(let data):
   case .error(let errorMessage):
}
```

Comment: KMM generates ObjC headers, there's no ObjC enum analog that can hold data. But you can generate swift code for your sealed classes using [KSwift](https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-kswift)

Comment: I've tried to use KSwift multiple times for my KMM Library but the generated xcframework still not generating the enum for Swift. It's still detected as empty protocol and the other UIState inside it detected as split class implementing the protocol. If you want to try it out for yourself, here's the link to the repository https://github.com/Fostahh/MySharedKMMLibrary . Thank you for the advice though! @PhilDukhov

Comment: Kotlin
`sealed interface UIState<out T> {
    object Loading : UIState<Nothing>
    data class Data<T>(val value: T) : UIState<T>
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : UIState<Nothing>
}
`

Generated xcframework
`public protocol UIState { }
public class UIStateLoading : KotlinBase, UIState { }
public class UIStateData<T> : KotlinBase, UIState where T : AnyObject {
    open var value: T? { get }
}
public class UIStateError : KotlinBase, UIState {
    open var throwable: KotlinThrowable { get }
}
`

Comment: As the kswift developer said from this medium https://medium.com/icerock/how-to-implement-swift-friendly-api-with-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-e68521a63b6d. From the Swift side Kotlin’s sealed interface looks like a set of classes with a common protocol. Of course, in this case, one cannot hope to check the completeness of the switch implementation, since it is not an enum.

Comment: KSwift can't convert your class to swift enum, it generates class with `Ks` suffix, e.g. `UIStateKs`, and you can convert `UIState` to `UIStateKs` and back using code generated by KSwift.